# Implementing event handler in singleton class in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, events, callback, singleton

I have WebSocket class configured as a singleton:

```
public class ViSoftAdsHub : ViewModelBase
{
    private static ViSoftAdsHub _instance;

    ViSoftAdsHub()
    {
        ConnectAsync();
    }
    public static ViSoftAdsHub Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ViSoftAdsHub();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Multiple object instances of any type can add a notification to this singleton:

```
public void AddNotification(string name, ConfigurationsConfigSectionAdd sourceConfig,Type t)
{
    NotificationObject no = new NotificationObject
    {
        ConnectionSettings = sourceConfig,
        Name = name,
        type = t
    };
    _Notifications.Add(name, no);
}
```

I need the callback only to be fired in the callback of the object who created the notification. Now, when a notification is received in the hub it fires on all callbacks on all objects.

This is the event implementation in the singleton:

```
protected virtual void OnNotification(ViSoftNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    EventHandler<ViSoftNotificationEventArgs> handler = Notification;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, e);
    }
}
public event EventHandler<ViSoftNotificationEventArgs> Notification;

public void OnMessage2(ViSoftNotificationEventArgs arg1, Type arg2)
{
    OnNotification(arg1 as ViSoftNotificationEventArgs);  
}
```

caller method of objects subscribing to the event:

```
hub = ViSoftAdsHub.Instance;
hub.Notification += new EventHandler<ViSoftNotificationEventArgs>(Hub_Notification);
hub.AddNotification(Name, SourceConfig, typeof(Sometype));
```

I also get a major memory leak.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want a singleton.

Comment: Not sure how to manage the connection part without the singleton.

Comment: Why not? What don't you understand?

Comment: Good question.. When I created to many instances of the Hub class (one per viewmodel) the CPU load went into 100%, so i figured that each instansiation created one new client.